# Tokenizer is not outputting anything

Tags: ruby

Someone just tell me already why this doesnt work please:

```rb
class Tokenizer
  def initialize
    @syntax_checks =
      / (?<number>\d++)
      | (?<linebreak>\R++)
      | (?<whitespace>\s++)
      | . #anything else
      /x
    @keywords =
      / (?<stdout>"stdp")
      /x
    @counter = 0
    @tokens = []
  end

  def tokenize(line, counter)
    @counter = counter
    line.scan(@keywords) do
      case
      when i = $~[:stdout]
        @tokens.append([i, "KEYWORD"])
        @counter += 4
        puts "a"
      else
        line.scan(@syntax_checks) do
          case
          when i = $~[:number]
            @tokens.append([i, "NUMBER"])
            @counter += 1
          when i = $~[:linebreak]
            @tokens.append(["\n", "LINEBREAK"])
            @counter += 1
          when i = $~[:whitespace]
            @tokens.append([" ", "WHITESPACE"])
            @counter += 1
          else
            if i in ["+","-","/","=","(",")"]
              @tokens.append([i, "LITERAL"])
              @counter += 1
            else
            end
          end
        end
      end
    end
    return @tokens
  end
end

tokenizer = Tokenizer.new

puts tokenizer.tokenize("stdp (1-2)", 0)
```

Output: ""

Expected output: "[["stdp", "KEYWORD"], ["(", "LITERAL"] ...

It is for a programming language and is just stripping out the tokens of a line, it is supposed to return them in the written format

Comment: I think that you're trying to match with `"stdp"` (quotes included). Is that intended? `line.scan(@keywords)` doesn't find any match because your string doesn't have any quotes.